# How work with a visual studio project in two different machines

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, project

In my home pc, I'm inside a LAN so my projects are access using localhost. In the WEB section of the project I use Local IIS

```
 http://localhost/ProjectName
```

[image]

But in my office the pc belong to a domain so my IIS is bound to

```
 http://myPc.myDomain.com/ProjectName
```

So how I can open the same Visual Studio solution on both PC?

Answer (score 0):

First, on the home PC make an entry such as this in the local **`hosts`** file:

```
127.0.0.1    myPc.myDomain.com
```

Second, also at the home PC, configure the **Website bindings in IIS**, so when IIS receives a request for `myPc.myDomain.com`, it knows which website should process the request.